# Rectangular and mipmap textures

Tags: opengl, textures

what is the use of rectangular textures if we have mipmap supporting NPOT textures? Is there any performance related or quality of image related improvement? 
Also, i think, mipmapping would take large amount of memory as it creates for every level. So, isn' it better to use rectangular textures?

Comment: You don't have to use mipmapping for normal (non-rectangular) textures, it's not a must. That being said, with the advent of NPOT textures (which are core since 10 years) there IMHO isn't any real use for rectangular textures at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rectangle textures:

1. Never have mipmaps.
2. Use non-normalized texture coordinates.

#1 isn't that important, as you can achieve the same effect by just using [glTexStorage2D](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexStorage2D) and [setting the number of mipmap levels to 1](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage#Immutable_storage), or by [setting the base/max level of the texture properly](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Mipmap_range) and/or using [min filtering parameters](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object#Filtering) that don't use mipmaps.

#2 is harder to emulate. The [texelFetch](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29#Direct_texel_fetches) function works in texture space, but this uses integer texture coordinates. Rectangle texture coordinates are floating-point values. This allows them to employ bilinear and even anisotropic filtering. You can't do that with `texelFetch`.

You can emulate rectangle textures by normalizing a texel-space texture coordinate. But this requires manual work: you have to either query the texture's size with `textureSize` or pass the size in a `uniform` to the shader. Then you have to do a division to normalize the coordinate. This may be what modern hardware does behind the scenes (especially since newer APIs like Vulkan don't have them), but if there's explicit support for rectangle textures, manual work will likely bypass it.

#2 is really the main reason you would *ever* use rectangle textures these days. They're great for render targets, because you can fetch values from them using window-space coordinates without needing to normalize the texture coordinates. But in general, they're very special-case texture types.

Questions of performance are purely speculative and hardware-specific.

Comment: +1 But in the end #2 just amounts to an additional multiplication for normal textures.

Comment: @ChristianRau: It's not just that; you have to get the texture's size. That requires either using `textureSize` (which may take up uniform resources) or using a uniform directly (which *will* take up uniform resources). And it's not a multiplication; it's a multiplication by the *inverse* of the size, which is rather more expensive. Yes, rectangle textures could be implemented by the compiler doing all of that for you. But if there's dedicated hardware for them, then this will give you added performance. And if it is... you haven't lost anything.

Comment: Well, Ok. That uniform might not hurt anybody, but in fact you got a valid point.

Comment: @NicolBolas Can you please elaborate your second point? this part " but they are floating-point values", how exactly floating point values?

Comment: @Roshan: I don't know what you want me to elaborate on. Floating point values are... floating point. You can be halfway between two texels, which is required for filtering. Integers can't be halfway between anything; they exactly specify a texel.